# Turning list contents into a string

Tags: string, vb.net, list

I have a list with x elements. I need a way that puts the contents of these into a string.

```
    Dim List As New ArrayList
    Dim Strin As String

    List.Add("Apple")
    List.Add("Bananna")
    List.Add("Carrot")

    For i = 0 To List.Count
        Strin = Strin + List(i)
    Next i
    Console.WriteLine(Strin)
```

This given an error saying that the index is out of bounds which I don't understand because I start at 0

Comment: The list index ranges from 0 to Count - 1. (Otherwise there would be Count + 1 entries in the list because it starts at 0.) Btw.: Use better variable names. In more complex programs you will have a lot of strings and lists. so names like `List` or `Strin` are not very useful. Name them `fruits` and `displayText` for instance.

Comment: @Ben711Gaming Don't use `ArrayList` for new development. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-6.0#remarks

Comment: @Ben711Gaming The desired string concatenation could also be done without a loop using something like this: `String.Join("", List.ToArray())`

Comment: @MatSnow In productive code `String.Join` is the right choice. But this is most likely an exercise about creating simple algorithms and learning how to use loops.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thank you for your help :) Also, I used these crappy names because I am just doing some small scale testing for a much bigger project for which I am currently working on

Comment: @MatSnow i tried this in a previous attempt but it didn't seem to work very well at all. But thank you anyway :)

Comment: @Ben711Gaming No, it will work and is IMO the best method. However, you must also take the previous advice to not use `ArrayList` ever and use `List(Of String)` instead. Just change the declaration to `Dim List As New List(Of String)()` and `Dim Strin = String.Join("", List)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes out of bounds because the index of a list starts from 0. Count is 0 only when your list is empty, if you want to iterate through a populated list you either do:

```
For i = 1 To List.Count
    Strin = Strin & List(i - 1)
Next i
```

Or:

```
For i = 0 To List.Count - 1
```

Or, my personal favourite:

```
For Each element in List
  Strin = Strin & element
Next
```

Comment: You don't have the choice! List indexes go from `0` to `Count - 1`. The [documentation of the `List(Of T)` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0#remarks) says: *Elements in this collection can be accessed using an integer index. Indexes in this collection are zero-based.*

Comment: yes i know, is there something wrong in the answer?

Comment: Okay, I see now that you are indexing with `i -1` in the first example. But looping with `1 To Count` is odd. I know, In the VB 6.0 world and in Office applications indexes were often 1-based. But in not the .NET world.

Comment: Yes, totally agree. I personally try to avoid `For` when you can use `For Each`

Comment: On top of the other commentary, `+` is not the correct string concatenation operator to use in vb.net: `&` is

Comment: they both work but ye, i've edited

Answer (score 2):

This exception caused by the last iteration of `for` loop. As [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement) says, `end` part is inclusive, so you should exclude it.
Try this:

```
For i = 0 To List.Count - 1
```